# can i assign value to an attribute outside the constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

i want to leave a declared attibute with its default value (no assignament in constructor or declaration) and then, in sub-classes, implement a interface that set the attibute using getter/setter of the main class, is that a correct method? (sorry for bad english)

more context of the problem:
i have a class "Product" and sub-classes "Packaged" "Cleaning" "Drinks" (i know is weird hehe), and i need to use a interface "Edible" that must set/get calories and expiration date, since i don't know how to attach  those attibutes to the subclass i got that idea
(i thought about using the Edible as direct subclass of Product but there are packaged items that are edible and not, so i don't know how to solve the inheritance problem. also i was asked to use edible as an interface)
again, sorry for bad english

edit: all the mentioned classes are abstract classes

Comment: No, interfaces cannot set instance variables that they don't know about. You'll have to set the instance variable in the *actual* child class, either through a provided setter, by calling an appropriate `super` constructor, or by making the field `protected`.

Comment: Every non-abstract class will have its own constructor, so can have all the parameters necessary. So I think there's something in your question that's missing.

Comment: What exactly were you asked to do? Also, note that interfaces never have access to instance fields of the classes implementing them, since interfaces don't have (non-static) fields.